# Heap - constructor and destructor, memory allocation

Tags: c++

I have a class with constructor and destructor and one other method.
When i create new instance of this class then it calls destructor somewhere and I dont know why.

```
class Heap
{
private:
    int *heap;
    int size;
    int heap_size;
public:
    Heap(int new_size)
    {
        size = new_size;
        heap_size = 0; 
        heap = (int*)malloc(new_size*sizeof(int)); //??? 
        //heap = new int[new_size]; //???
    }
    ~Heap()
    { 
        free(heap);
    }
    void add(int alfa)
    {
    // something
    }
};

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    int k = rand() % 100 + 1;
    Heap *name = &Heap(k);
    Heap *name2 = new Heap(k); //what's the diffrence?
    while (k > 0)
    {
        name->add(rand()); // doesn't work, because destructor is called before
        k--;
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `&Heap(k)` You're returning the address of a temporary.

Comment: `main.cpp(31): warning C4238: nonstandard extension used: class rvalue used as lvalue`  That should be an error, but Microsoft's compiler defaults to broken. Never ever ignore that warning.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc` inside your class instead of `new []`? (but then again, you should be using `std::vector` or `std::array` instead of raw memory allocations where possible).

Answer (score 3):

In the process running this non-standard piece of code<sup>1</sup>, which would most likely produce *undefined behaviour*<sup>2</sup> anyway, this line

```
Heap *name = &Heap(k);
```

produces a temporary `Heap` object that gets destroyed at the end of that full expression. This results in the destructor being called.

Note that the fact remains that your class is quite fragile because it does not follow [*the rule of three (five)*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three). Copying `Heap` objects would lead to double-deletes.

---

<sup>1 For good reasons, standard C++ does not allow to take the address of a temporary.</sup>
<sup>2 This construction leaves you with a dangling pointer. Technically, de-referencing `name` is what would cause undefined behaviour.</sup>

Comment: That is ill-formed. Are MS ever going to change that completely broken default? It causes so many beginners to write dreadful mistakes that the language says shouldn't even compile.

Comment: @JonathanWakely Right, I added a note about that.